# My UrlRewrite IHttpModule remove my second QueryString

Tags: c#, query-string, ihttpmodule

I have a custom url rewriter function that works fine. But when i are going to use a second querystring on my url, that remove the second querystring.

my friendly url: /gallery/view-ablum/?q=1
i the code: Page.aspx?id=22&q=1 , when i have past RewritePath(...) the remove &q=1 from my real page. I don't now who to fix this, i can't figure it out.

```
context.RewritePath(ci.PageUrl + ta + "&q=" + q, false);
```

Is there a IsPostBack for IHttpModule?

Comment: Please expand (e.g. processing code) for query string, not clear what you are trying to achieve or what the problem is (especially as "second query string" doesn't make sense, unless you mean second parameter in the query string).

Answer (score 1):

for the question, "Is there a IsPostBack for IHttpModule"

bool isPostBack = !string.IsNullOrEmpty(context.Request.Form["__VIEWSTATE"])

..or introduce your own hidden field when not using viewstate (which is probably safer anyway)

Answer (score 0):

> Is there a IsPostBack for IHttpModule?

Will depend on which event the module is subscribing to. Earlier HttpApplication events will occur before IsPostBack is determined.

But IsPostBack is WebForm specific (e.g. not used in ASP.NET MVC) is may not be available outside the Page class.

Answer (score 0):

Well i get this error code when i debugg : `CurrentNotification    'context.CurrentNotification' threw an exception of type 'System.PlatformNotSupportedException'    System.Web.RequestNotification {System.PlatformNotSupportedException}`

and i found this

```
- Base ( "For this operation requires IIS integrated pipeline mode.") System.SystemException (System.PlatformNotSupportedException)
```